# How to remove duplicate value from object arraylist and sort

Tags: android, object, arraylist, comparison

I have one `recyclerview` where i am appending list with 1 loadmore data

my requirement is to do not allow to add duplicate object data in main arraylist and sort array but it's not working.

i done some thing like this to remove duplicate data but it's removing all data one by one

```
newElementsList.forEach { first ->
            mList.remove(first)
}
```

newElementsList is get new data every 5 min  and mList is main list(it's value assign on start and on loadmore)

in model i added this

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
            if (other !is ChatData) {
                return false
            }
            val that: ChatData = other as ChatData

            // Custom equality check here.
            return this.id == that.id
        }
```

but it's removing item one by one from the main list

How can i achieve this both main and new arraylist have same data type

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At present the removal for each element one by one creates an overhead, a better alternative for this use-case is a TreeSet (log(n) time for operations like add, remove and contains)

You could use an `TreeSet.addAll()` to pass a collection and it will maintain the order for you as well as ensure there are no duplicates present.

Make sure to implement `Comparable` interface on your model for the set to infer the natural ordering.

Please read the documentation for more information on the usage:

1. TreeSet - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html
2. Comparable interface - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html